# Azure SQL: Audit Triggers and Ownership Chaining

Tags: triggers, azure-sql-database, audit

I have two tables, T1 and T2, in two different schemas, S1 and S2, respectively.  I have written a trigger, TR1 (with no EXECUTE AS clause), on T1 which logs inserts (I), updates (U), and deletes (D) into T2, which has an identical schema as T1, with some additional metadata columns.  S1, T1, S2, T2, and TR1 all are owned by dbo.

I have created a role, R1, which has S, I, U, and D rights to S1 (and therefore, T1).  The role also allows S on S2 (and therefore T2), but denies I, U, and D.  I have created a user, U1, and assigned role R1 to this user.

Under the user context of U1, if I try to I, U, or D on T2, that is denied, as expected.  However, if I I, U, or D into T1, the audit rows are successfully inserted into T2.  This is the behavior that I wanted, but was wondering the reason for this, as U1 has been explicitly denied these privileges.

Is this because of ownership chaining, such that U1's privileges are never checked on T2 when TR1 runs, or something else?

Azure SQL version is Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Jul 23 2021 13:14:19   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation

--

Trigger code added:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG ON dbo.T1
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN;

DECLARE @Operation CHAR(1);

SET @Operation =    (
                        CASE
                            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED) AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DELETED) THEN 'U'
                            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED) THEN 'I'
                            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DELETED) THEN 'D'
                            ELSE NULL
                        END
                    );

IF @Operation = 'I'
    BEGIN;
        INSERT INTO     adt.T1(Operation, ID, C1)
        SELECT          @Operation, ID, C1
        FROM            INSERTED;
    END;

IF @Operation = 'D'
    BEGIN;
        INSERT INTO     adt.T1 (Operation, ID, C1)
        SELECT          @Operation, ID, C1
        FROM            DELETED;
    END;

IF @Operation = 'U'
    BEGIN;
        INSERT INTO     adt.T1 (Operation, ID, C1)
        SELECT          @Operation, i.ID, i.C1
        FROM            INSERTED i
        INNER JOIN      DELETED d
        ON              i.ID = d.ID
                        -- Hash indicated columns of INSERTED and DELETED to determine if there are any real changes.
        WHERE           (SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', (SELECT i.ID, i.C1 FROM (SELECT NULL AS X) t FOR XML AUTO)))
                        <>
                        (SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', (SELECT d.ID, d.C1 FROM (SELECT NULL AS X) t FOR XML AUTO)));
    END;

END;
```

Comment: So to paraphrase, User is correctly denied IUD operations on T2, so why is a trigger (on another table) raised by the same user able to insert records into this table

Comment: As far as I can see, this scenario only works with EXECUTE AS, that is the whole point of that clause. Please post your trigger create script to verify

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Trigger code added

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Also added that tables are in different schemas, and that the privileges were issued on the schemas, not on the tables themselves.  Everything in play owned by dbo.

Comment: Ok, yes this is ownership chaining in action, because you are securing at the schema level. In other scenarios you might consider securing the target tables directly to prevent this behaviour, but in an audit context it is useful because we can use the current context to log the curent user and privs into the audit table, we would lose some of this info if the trigger used Execute As. For strictly non-audit based scenarios you need to be aware that ownership chaining can expose your secured tables to updates you might not have been expecting.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller All good. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, appreciated.

Comment: Hi VBlades, if @ChrisSchaller's response in the comment resolved your issue, I request you to please post your solution as answer to help other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller If you're happy to repost your comment as a solution, happy to give you the points for it.  If you don't get to it in a day or two, I will post as the solution.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, I'm just trying to find a good reference, ownership chaining is simple enough in theory but to demonstrate when it goes right or wrong in production, so how and when to exploit would be useful

Comment: @ChrisSchaller FYI I was able to replicate the behaviour on tables as the securables instead of schemas.  You may want to give it a go yourself as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, yes this is ownership chaining in action, because you are securing at the schema level.

> **[Understanding SQL Server Ownership Chaining](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6394/understanding-sql-server-ownership-chaining)**
> When there’s an ownership chain, *security is ignored on the object being referenced*.

In this case there is an *owership chain* because both schemas have the same owner, and this means that the privileges are **NOT** re-evaluated for the trigger execution when it accesses the assumed *secured* schema.

> To be clear, the execution context has not changed, there is no `EXECUTE AS` or impersonation going on. The operations against table T2 are still operating within the context of the original caller, but the ownership chaining rules means that access rules are simple not re-evaluated, it doesn't even try to check.

Ownership chaining is an optimisation feature of SQL Server, in many cases it improves query throughput by allowing access rules to be evaluated once rather than re-evaluating every possible securable context it the engine only re-evaluates when the contexts are secured by a different owner.

This is a primary reason why the *Owner* of a schema matters, and why you might specify different arbitrary owners created specifically for different schemas.

In the case of Audit/Change logging, we can take advantage of this behaviour to maintain the integrity of our data by blocking users who deliberately attempt to modify the audit records, while still allowing those users to execute queries and commands that might have side effects that will insert rows into the audit tables.

Because the user context has not been tampered with we can still capture and record information about the current user context and include that in the metadata that you may be recording about the operation.

> For strictly non-audit based scenarios you need to be aware that ownership chaining can expose your secured tables to updates you might not have been expecting.